# How can I give the opportunity to choose weather I want to overwrite an existing upload file or not?

Tags: php

I searched everywhere to find a tutorial for the simple need I have, but until now I couldn't find an answer and cannot get my script work.

My script should do the following:

- user chooses a file to upload and click submit
- script checks if the file already exists
- if the file does not exist then upload file to destination
- if the file already exists then ask user: "Overwrite?"
- If the user clicks "Overwrite?" then overwrite the file

index.php

```
<form action="check.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <button type="submit" value="upload">Upload</button>
</form>
```

check.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
   $file = $_FILES['file'];
   $upload = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
   $target_file = 'files/'.basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

   if (file_exists($target_file)) {
     echo "File already exist";                  
     echo "<form action='overwrite.php' method='post'>
       <input type='hidden' name='upload' value='$upload'>
       <input type='hidden' name='target_file' value='$target_file'>
       <button type='submit'> Overwrite?</button>
     </form>";
   } 
   else {

      move_uploaded_file($upload, $target_file);  
      echo "File was successfully uploaded";  
      echo "<a href='index.php'><button>back</button></a>";  
   }    
}
    ?>
```

overwrite.php

```
<?php
    $upload = $_POST["upload"];
    $target_file = $_POST["target_file"];
    move_uploaded_file($upload, $target_file);
    echo "The file is overwritten"; 
?>
```

Comment: Include a checkbox, check the value of that checkbox in the POSTed variables and if it is ticked, delete the file. Rather than upload and then ask, the user can decide ahead of time whether or not to delete / overwrite ~ amounts to the same thing

Comment: Some rules of web programming:
- Do not use user file names as valid ones, do not use it on your own server without escaping it.
- Always check that an error did not occur.

You would check the file name or the file content ?

Comment: hello, thank you, can you give an example? I do not know exactly how you mean it. Is the way I did it possible? with posting the values to overwrite.php? Do you mean put a checkbox to check.php?

Answer (score 1):

The scripts that you have won't work as-is, because you cannot preset hidden field values in order to have the user upload a file.  Additionally, even if it did work, it would require that the file be uploaded twice.

Ideally, it would be best if you could check whether or not the file existed and was to be overwritten before the user spent any time actually uploading the file.  But this depends on how you dictate that the file exists.

Are you going to say that the file exists if the filename that the user provides matches (as your code seems to do now)?  As Loenix mentioned, relying on the user to provide the name of the file as a way to store it isn't a good idea.  You could use the contents.. we store files using the `sha1()` value as the filename.  This way, files that are the same (regardless of their name) don't take up disk space, and files that are different (even with the same name) can co-exist).  The metadata (file name, path, etc) are stored in a database.

However you end up making this determination, what you'll want to do is to first submit an AJAX request to the server that checks for the existence of the file, and if it exists, prompt the user to overwrite.  Only if the user chooses to overwrite, or if the file doesn't exist, is the file actually uploaded to the server and saved.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful answer. Because I am a beginner it is difficult to implement exactly what you said, because I never worked with Ajax. But I will give it a try

Comment: @Jarla, if you end up putting some code together that you're having difficulty with, feel free to post it as a new question, then comment here with a link to that question, and I will be happy to examine it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add a checkbox to your form to confirm 'Overwriting':

```
<input type='checkbox' name='overwriteIfExists' value='1'>
```

Then in your form processing:

```
if (file_exists($target_file)) {

    if(isset($_POST['overwriteIfExists'])){
        // overwrite file
    } else {
       // dont overwrite file
    } 

}
```

Checkbox values are only sent if they are checked, so if the checkbox has not been checked, `$_POST['overwriteIfExists']` wont exist and `(isset($_POST['overwriteIfExists']))` will be `false`

Comment: The OP asked that the user only be presented with the choice to overwrite if the file was verified by the script to exist.

Comment: Hi thank you, but I need the question to overwrite not in the form, I need it on the second page after it is checked weather the file already exists

Comment: @NickCoons OK.. .. Note to self: 'read the question' - Thanks

Comment: @Chris: There is a form on check.php which asks the user to overwrite. My form works well, the only problem is, that the file is not beeing overwritten